# Update SET new SubString Name

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have this Items named as following :

`LordFire Nexus Bolt
Nexus Right Leg
The Bone of Nexus
|cff00000Nexus Bright L`

So what i want their names to be changed from having 'Nexus' in the string To have 'Lyna' instead

Example :

`LordFire Lyna Bolt
Lyna Right Leg
The Bone of Lyna
|cff00000Lyna Bright L`

I've been using this SQL since names was at the start of the string but now it's randomly at start / middle / end and even close to other characters

```
UPDATE Table SET name = CONCAT("Lyna ", SUBSTRING(name, LENGTH("Nexus ")+1)) WHERE name like "Nexus%";
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oh thank you i forgot to add the mysql tag

Comment: I'm sure mysql has a `replace` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below Code

UPDATE table set name = Replace(name, 'Nexus', 'Lyna')

Comment: As simple as effective, thank you very much .. i was just getting it so Complicated.